# Double Locking on Normal Map - Is this Safe?

Tags: java, performance, concurrency

The majority of access would be reads and the map itself will be relatively small.  That said would the following be safe, my tests show that the results are faster than a ConcurrentHashMap (at least on 1.7x).

```
   volatile Map<String, Object> mapV;

   public Object getV(String key) {
         Object value = mapV.get(key);
         if (value == null) {
                synchronized(this) {
                       value = mapV.get(key);
                       if (value == null) {
                             value = new Object();
                             Map<String, Object> copy = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                             copy.putAll(mapV);
                             copy.put(key, value);
                             mapV = Collections.unmodifiableMap(copy);
                       }
                }
         }
         return value;
   }
```

Comment: Have you tried the `Collections.synchronizedMap()` implementation? It uses roughly the same system, and is also known to be faster than a `ConcurrentHashMap` (with a relative small size)

Comment: @n247s I think they are quite different.  A synchronized map would force a lock on every get.  This forces the lock only on secondary gets.  The expense is that I need to recopy all contents when introducing a new key.

Comment: Do you really need the copy-on-write?

Comment: @JimmyB Since the map is not thread safe yes you do as confirmed by John Vint.  Volatile gives us nothing if we just modify the map directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be thread-safe. Since your map assignments are volatile any thread which sees `mapV.get(key) != null` will be hitting a volatile read and so would be safe.

As an edit: I would be surprised if this is actually faster or if it would be faster with a lot of data. I would definitely use a `ConcurrentHashMap` instead of this implementation.

Comment: A `SynchronizedHashMap` (retrieved with `Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>())`) is faster than a `ConcurrentHashMap` if there is not a lot of data. More specifically, there is no performance penatly in comparison to the backing `Map` implementation if there is only one Thread accesing the map at the same time. So for a Thread-safe-low-trafic implementation the `SynchronizedHashMap` is the way to go. Otherwise a `ConcurrentHashMap` is the choice of preference. (Note that iteration on a `SynchronizedHashMap` returned by the `Collections` class needs to be implemented by the user itself.)

Comment: I have to disagree with you. The `ConcurrentHashMap` is just like a regular `HashMap` with the addition, of maybe, a volatile load on reads. They both use `synchronized` for mutexing so any optimizations there would be the same. In my opinion, there really isn't a good reason to use the `synchronizedMap` over `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: For most cases a `ConcurrentHashMap` will do. The difference totaly rely on the amount of data, the amount of accesing Threads and the operation types. Here is an article on this topic analysing the different operations and its performance. http://gregluck.com/blog/archives/2009/06/performance-problems-in-concurrenthashmap-vs-synchronized-hashmap/

Comment: I'll fully read the article. However, this was written in 2009 and the ConcurrentHashMap got a big update to address space problems (attributed to Segments being an `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer`). I'd like to see an update with the newer ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: Thats true, I forgat about that issue. In that case it might be worth it to benchmark both implementations again.

Comment: My testing shows that Collections.synchronizedMap is not the way to go (for my purposes).